# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_REPL_INPUT]: Listeners for `uncaughtException` cannot be used in the REPL

Tags: npm, truffle

I am using **truffle** in windows and everything went well. I've successfully set up development network. But when I try to run `test` from the `truffle(develop)` console this error shows -

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_REPL_INPUT]: Listeners for 'uncaughtException' cannot be used in the REPL`
but if I open another console while running `truffle(develop)` console in first console and run:

`truffle migrate --reset` and `truffle test`

then the test will be executed well. Is there any way to run `test` command from `truffle(develop)` console?

[test command on truffle(develop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUOBJ.png)

Comment: Hi @sayhan, Could u plz mention your node version?

Comment: @Aldo my node version is `v12.18.0`. I am working in virtualBox